# ActivatedRoute isn't working in Service

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

## ActivatedRoute in Services

### The Problem

I was trying to use ActivatedRoute in a service and was noticing that it didn't seem to be tracking the route that I was currently on. In fact it wouldn't seem to pick up any route. It took me far too long to figure out what was going on and I wasn't able to find many helpful answers online(probably because most people are a lot quicker than me :) ).

Just wanted to make sure that I posted something so that some others can find the solution faster.

Here's what my code looked like when I was having the issue.

```
@Injectable()
export class ImdbService {

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  closeDetails(): void {
    this.detailsOpened = false;
    this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

Comment: This seems to be by design: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12884 | https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12938

Answer (score 9):

### My Solution

Because the services seem to not have the same interaction with ActivatedRoute when injected as the components do my solution was to pass the ActivatedRoute as a param in the service call I was using.

Here's what the solution that worked for me looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class ImdbService {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  closeDetails(currentRoute): void {
    this.detailsOpened = false;
    this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: currentRoute});
  }
```

And in the component:

```
export class MovieDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(..., private route: ActivatedRoute ) { }

  closeDetails() {
    this.imdbService.closeDetails(this.route);
  }
```

### Got something better?

If anyone has a better or even just a different solution to this issue or if there's a good reason to do this in an entirely different way I'd love to see it.

Comment: I wouldn't use a service at all for this. Interaction with the URL is a component's responsibility, not a service responsibility in my opinion. So I would use the service to do the fancy logic and then return a value indicating if the details can be closed

Comment: @NicoTimmerman in any real case application routing is not responsibility of presentation layer (components). Even just from reusability point of view components shouldn't be concerned about how they or the whole application is routed.

Answer (score 4):

Inject your service directly within the component

```js
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ImdbService], // provide your service here so it will be instanciated with your component.
})

export class MovieDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(..., private imdbService: ImdbService ) { }

  closeDetails() {
    this.imdbService.closeDetails();
  }
```